# Karma+mocha Erro com o module Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd

#### Resumo

Estou criando um seed para projeto modular com AngularJS + Browserify + BabelJS. Estou implementando a parte de teste de unidade.

#### Problema

Quando chamo o modulo angular ele me retorna o erro

> TypeError: module is not a function
>       at Context. (test.bundle.js:10:5)

Isto acontece para $controller, $scope...

#### TESTE

```
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("BaseController", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    module('MyApp');
  });
  it("Test1", () => {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Não estou usando CommonJS na hora de executar os teste, ele gera um bundler para mim de todos os teste e joga na pasta ./dist;

#### Código

Branch é `test-implement`

GitHub: [code](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-modular/tree/master)

O projeto é open-source dicas são muito bem vindas.

#### Para Rodar

- git checkout -b test-implement origin/test-implement
- git checkout test-implement
- npm install
- bower install
- gulp server-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução minha foi o alteração do chamado do module `module('MyApp')`para `angular.mocks.module('MyApp')` ficando assim assim:

```
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("thes base controller", () => {
  var scope, controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module("MyApp")); // modificado aqui.

  beforeEach(inject(($controller, $rootScope) => {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var ctrl = $controller('BaseController', { $scope:scope });
  }));
  it("Test1", ()  => {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

### Referencia

[angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)